# What’s a good name for someone who lives up to their name? Like, century lives up to 100 years

Tags: creative-writing

I’m writing a story about people called century and decade (decade is a ghost) and their kind needs a name. Something to do with time and death, or names and time or anything along those lines.

Comment: This might be a better fit for ell.se or english.se.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Please take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, you might find them helpful. Your question *might* be a better fit for English.SE, although I am unsure. Here, I am afraid it is off topic, as you're asking us *what* to write, essentially a brainstorming question. We don't answer those, as they can potentially have an infinite number of answers, and are of little use to anybody but you. Our scope is questions about *how* to write - use of language, tropes, structure etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You're talking about [aptonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym).  Unfortunately, however, this is not really on topic for our site.  Single word requests are best at http://english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The condition could loosley be called nominative determinism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism

If you want a made up word then thanatochrononomical seems to supply the right morphemes: "Death", "Time", "Name" from greek. "Thanatochrons" for short or perhaps TCNs or even corrupted over time to "Teeken" - up to you.
Alternativley Thanatonoms "Death names" maybe shortens to Thanoms.

As another possibility, you can look at the language native to that group you are talking about, what are their words for death, name, time?

Answer (score 0):

A term that describes itself, such as *polysyllabic*, is *autological* (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox#The_paradox) for an amusing consequence of this concept).